# FeatVPN - Setup Failed

Tags: vpn

I was using Feat VPN, when suddenly it wouldn't connect anymore. I uninstalled the app and wiped its data, then tried to reinstall it and run the set-up. However it stopped and failed on TUN Device Start 2 of 2.

I then checked the log on the app. It showed 'uncaught.exception.java.lang.illegalargumentexception`.

I also checked other forums and tutorials. They said check my `/dev/tun` file and make sure that its permission is set to `rw-rw----` and ownership to `uses= system` and `group=vpn`. I did and it was already set to said permissions.

My brother and I have the same phone model. I tried to look for `/dev/tun` (hoping that I could copy/paste to my phone), but his phone doesn't have a tun file. However, he also uses Feat VPN. Can someone explain to me what is happening? My phone runs on Android ICS 4.0.4.

LOGCAT:
http://pastebin.com/Zd97gecr

Comment: Probably a custom kernel with tunnelling capabilities is already built in? Can you enclose the logcat?

Comment: @t0mm13b maybe its already built in on my brother's phone, so what should I do? should I delete the /dev/tun file on my phone? how can I enclose the logcat?

Comment: don't delete the /dev/tun file on your phone. You comfortable with command line? plug in usb cable to handset, `adb logcat > /sdcard/logcat.txt`, then `adb pull /sdcard/logcat.txt`, open it up, copy paste into your question above. You need to run this at the point of running the setup of Feat VPN, to ensure that pertinent log is captured.

Comment: @t0mm13b I just formatted my computer, I dont think I have ADB here, but maybe I can copy the whole log of the app?

Comment: Ok, or email it to yourself and open it, copy/paste..

Comment: @t0mm13b is it really that long??? ok I'll paste it on my question.

Comment: @t0mm13b I can't paste it on my question the log consists of 47000+ characters. what do you want me to do?

Comment: Ok, use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and include the linky in your question.

Comment: @t0mm13b done sir!

Answer (score 0):

Alright...line 5026, is the culprit:

```
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): [ 4] 2013-07-31 22:56:09 [   7206] [78752] [   Test] Invoking test to front listener
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): [ 5] 2013-07-31 22:56:09 [   7206] [78752] [   Test] Starting test [5]
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): [ 6] 2013-07-31 22:56:09 [   7206] [78752] [   Test] Invoking test start listener
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): [ 7] 2013-07-31 22:56:09 [   7206] [78752] [   Test] Waiting for L2TP tunnel completion (0 s)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): 2013-07-31 22:56:10 [   7206] [57328] [  Proxy] Uncaught exception
E/FeatVPN ( 7206): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad address
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at android.net.VpnService$Builder.addDnsServer(VpnService.java:392)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at android.net.VpnService$Builder.addDnsServer(VpnService.java:410)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at com.featvpn.sdk.a.createTun2(Unknown Source)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at com.featvpn.sdk.a.createTun(Unknown Source)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at com.featvpn.sdk.Proxy.v(Unknown Source)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at com.featvpn.sdk.Proxy.run(Unknown Source)
E/FeatVPN ( 7206):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Reading this, it looks like the proxy address was set up incorrectly which explained why it crashed. *You have it set correctly?*

It might be best to log this with FeatVPN's developers as to why its happening when going through the setup procedure. Also noticed in the log, you are running Greenify, would that be clashing or conflicting with FeatVPN.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm using it before, And it works, perfectly fine. I dont know how to setup the proxy, all I do is to load the preconfigured tunnels after the setup. I'm thinking, if I will reflash my rom again, I'm sure it will work,. Is there a way to wipe the data corupted by featVPN then I'll install it again like a newly flashed phone?

Comment: the developers said that my net.dns1 is set to 0.0.0.0 and there's no way that featVPN changed this because the application does not require root access